# Fetch one data from column with multiple data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have inserted multiple data in one column but can't select one data from this column eg: only get data b from col_1

```
col_1   | col_2|
--------+------+
a,b,c,d |e     |
----------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data in the column is structured consistently, you can define your own function to split the column into multiple columns:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER FUNCTION `SPLIT_STR`(
  x VARCHAR(255),     # Input
  delim VARCHAR(12),  # Delimiter
  pos INT             # Position or Field
) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Use it as follows:

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR(col1, ',', 2) FROM table; # Results in 'b'
```

Comment: Yes. I use this function in my own MySQL db

Comment: Thank you so much.. this was my first custom function in mysql and your answer worked perfectly.. so you deserve bounty and upvote.

Comment: You're welcome. However, I will advice you to use multiple columns in the future, as this will drastically increase performance and readability. And perhaps you can use this function to rearrange your data.

Answer (score 0):

Simply You can use explode(',', $data); function
but I recommend this method to work with multiple data:

```
<?php
// Your data
$data = 'a,b,c,d';
// Convert string to array
$data = explode(',', $data);

// Encode data and save it into database
$encoded_data = json_encode($data);

// Return data from database and convert it to array
$decoded_data = json_decode($encoded_data);

// Get item from returned array
echo $decoded_data[2];

echo '<pre>';
print_r($encoded_data);
echo '<br>';
print_r($decoded_data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: good idea when we using php. but not useful when we are in another language. This is why i mentioned jsp in tag.